# Is there any way we can override the django.request and change the logic for cookie parsing?

Tags: django, session-cookies

On Django 1.9.9, if any value of the cookie contains a space, then the Django 1.9 would not parse any of the cookies and hence, csrftoken validation would fail as well. We are thinking of fixing the cookie parsing logic on Django request.

Comment: you can check if this is fixed in newer version of Django.

Comment: We upgraded to Django 1.9.10 from 1.9.9 and it looks like they have fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We upgraded to Django 1.9.10 from 1.9.9 and it looks like they have fixed this issue.

The cookie parsing logic if fixed here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/1.9.10/.